# fail2ban SSH jail change action REJECT to DROP

Tags: debian, ssh, security, iptables, fail2ban

I am trying to configure a simple SSH jail with `fail2ban`.

Below is the configuration of the jail in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` :

```
[sshd]

# To use more aggressive sshd modes set filter parameter "mode" in jail.local:
# normal (default), ddos, extra or aggressive (combines all).
# See "tests/files/logs/sshd" or "filter.d/sshd.conf" for usage example and details.
#mode   = normal
enabled = true
port    = ssh
maxretry = 3
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
banaction = iptables-multiport[name=sshd, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
```

After I tried 3 unsuccesful ssh login on my server, we can see my IP (anonymised) is blacklisted:

```
fail2ban-client status sshd
    Status for the jail: sshd
    |- Filter
    |  |- Currently failed: 0
    |  |- Total failed:     3
    |  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
    `- Actions
       |- Currently banned: 1
       |- Total banned:     1
       `- Banned IP list:   X.X.X.X
```

And here is the rule configured on `iptables` by `fail2ban`:

```
iptables -S
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -N f2b-sshd
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
    -A f2b-sshd -s X.X.X.X/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    -A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

When I try to login again, I receive this message: `ssh: connect to host <hostname_anonymised> port 22: Connection refused`

But here is the problem, I don't want to receive an `icmp port unreachable` message like above, it is a security issue.

I want that fail2ban DROP silently (instead of REJECT with icmp). I tried to change the configuration of the jail to specify the `banaction` I want, but I couldn't find the right parameter to tell jail2ban to `DROP silently` instead of `REJECT with icmp`.

How can I configure that in `fail2ban` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `iptables` actions have `blocktype` [parameter](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/3e6a60f9407596586fe39fa54fd63818c0972b7b/config/action.d/iptables.conf#L128), that can be overwritten:

- either globally in `action.d/iptables.conf`:

```ini
[Definition]
blocktype = DROP
```

(for default upstream config of latest fail2ban version, older as well as maintained   versions may have different includes for the actions you use as banaction)

- or in `jail.local` in default or jail section:

```ini
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-multiport[blocktype=DROP]
banaction_allports = iptables-allports[blocktype=DROP]
```

Don't forget to restart fail2ban hereafter.

Also note https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2217#issuecomment-423248516 for more info about REJECT vs DROP.

Comment: Hello,

thanks for your answer ,it worked ! :)
Here is what worked for me :

In file `jail.local` I putted in the ssh jail section :
`banaction = iptables-multiport[name=sshd, port=ssh, protocol=tcp, blocktype=DROP]`

And restarted fail2ban service.

Unfortunately if I try to change the value in the default section in `jail.local`, it doesn't seems to work.

And thanks for sharing the link but I am already aware of the difference between DROP and REJECT in firewall rules, I am a network and security engineer myself, but It was my first time using fail2ban.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help, have a great day ! :)

Answer (score 0):

To configure fail2ban to perform a silent block (DROP) instead of rejecting (REJECT) with an ICMP message, you can follow these steps:

Open the `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` file in a text editor.

Add or modify the following line in the [sshd] section to specify the desired block action:

```
banaction = iptables-multiport[name=sshd, port=ssh, protocol=tcp, action=drop]
```

This configuration tells `fail2ban` to use the drop action instead of the default reject action when blocking SSH connections.

Save the changes to the jail.local file.

Restart the fail2ban service to apply the new configuration:

```
sudo service fail2ban restart
```

With this configuration, fail2ban will use the drop action instead of the reject action with an ICMP message when blocking IP addresses in the SSH jail.

This will provide a silent block without sending ICMP reject messages.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for you answer, but it didn't work, here is what I did :

`cp -v /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local`
`nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local`



`cat /etc/fail2ban/jail.local | grep 'sshd' -A 5 | grep banaction`
`banaction = iptables-multiport[name=sshd, port=ssh, protocol=tcp, action=drop]`

`service fail2ban restart`


I tried again 3 unsuccesful SSH connection (anonymised IP), but the action didn't changed.

`iptables -S`
        [...]
 `-A f2b-sshd -s X.X.X.X/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`

Comment: Maybe I need to remove "banaction" of [sshd] section from /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf ?
Maybe this file overwrite the configuration of the jail.local file ?

Comment: Hello again,

I tried to remove the line `banaction` from `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` (and kept it in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`) then restarted the service and tried again 3 unsucessful SSH connection, but it did'nt change the iptables action.